# Postgres does not use index when sorting and joining

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, indexing, database-performance

I have a parent-child structure and I'm trying to select join of those two tables sorted by `from_time` column, but Postgres doesn't use the index, but sorts the result set on it's own.

I'm trying to guess what's the reason behind that, as the whole result set contains 75 000 rows. Tried also with result set as big as 500 000 but it ended up the same.

To give some overview about the size of the relations, `p_table` contains only 15 rows and `child_table` 75 000.

**Parent table**

```
CREATE TABLE public.p_table (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  from_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  to_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX from_time_idx ON p_table USING BTREE (from_time);
```

**Child table**

```
CREATE TABLE public.child_table (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  p_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES public.p_table (id)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
CREATE INDEX p_id_idx ON child_table USING BTREE (p_id);
```

My select looks like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM p_table p LEFT OUTER JOIN TRADE child_table t ON p.id = t.p_id
ORDER BY p.from_time ASC;
```

The output of `EXPLAIN` tells that index has not been used.

```
Sort  (cost=21181.56..21369.06 rows=75000 width=158) (actual time=256.995..275.618 rows=75000 loops=1)
  Output: all columns listed
  Sort Key: p.from_time
  Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 13640kB
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.34..3313.59 rows=75000 width=158) (actual time=0.829..166.747 rows=75000 loops=1)
        Output: all columns listed
        Hash Cond: (t.p_id = p.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on public.child_table t  (cost=0.00..2281.00 rows=75000 width=134) (actual time=0.493..127.786 rows=75000 loops=1)
              Output: all columns listed
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.15..1.15 rows=15 width=24) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=15 loops=1)
              Output: p.id, p.from_time, p.to_time
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
              ->  Seq Scan on public.p_table p  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=15 width=24) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=15 loops=1)
                    Output: p.id, p.from_time, p.to_time
Total runtime: 282.717 ms
```

Comment: 75K records in 282ms isn't that bad ....

Comment: Note: setting `work_mem` to a lower value (64 is the lowest) and possibly `random_page_cost` to a lower value (1.5 .. 2.0) will probably seduce the optimiser to abandon its favourite hash join. Note2: `LEFT OUTER JOIN TRADE` what is **TRADE** ?

Comment: Also play with `effective_cache_size` perhaps, and try turning off `enable_sort` for debugging.

Comment: If `p_table` has only 15 records, then I have a hard time imagining any query which would use its index -- using an index would *increase* the number of blocks to read (read the index in, read the single block that the table is in vs. just read the single block the table is in).

Comment: @PeterEisentraut: combining joop's settings with a sane setting for `effective_cache_size` does the trick. OP probably still has the *factory* settings. Reduction for hash-->> index plan switch is only ~50% here.